# What is bone space, armature space, object space, world space, local space?

Tags: python, bones, coordinates

So, I thought I understood Local space and World space but then I started seeing "Bone space", "Armature space", and "Object space" in tutorials. Now I'm just so confused. How do Bone, Armature, and Object spaces compare to World and Local spaces? I tried searching to no avail.

You don't have to go into detail. I'm sure I'll be able to figure things out in a minimal amount of information.

Thanks! :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of spaces in the constraints section of the blender manual is fairly good: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/interface/common.html#space-types

If you are familiar with the concept of local space vs world space, then object/armature/bone spaces are particular local spaces. Object space is the local space for a given object (e.g. mesh, curve, empty etc). Armature space is the object space of an armature, but is especially relevant in pose mode when contrasting with bone space, which is of course the local space for an individual bone.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine each object as its own universe with its own version of where the center is, where up is, where down is, where left/right is, what scale to use, etc and the only way to enter it is to go into TAB/Edit mode.